# positioning a popover using twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

if I have a popover on an `<a>` element and call it as follows

```
$(function () {
    $('#element').popover({
        placement:'top',
        title:'some title',
        content: $('#some-div').html()
    });
});
```

the popover displays top center of the element, how do I get the popover to display top-right or top left of the element?

Comment: Sadly there is only: top | bottom | left | right  .... and since it hardcodes the position it's not easy to just fix with some CSS. I think the only soloution is to set a minus margin to correct it. But i don't exactly understand how you would want it to look?

Answer (score 7):

You can add to the styles of the standard popover layout to move the popover where you want. Here is the standard popover layout taken directly from bootstrap-popover.js:

```
<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>
```

Therefore to move it say 15px to the right you can add the following to your style:

```
.popover {margin-left: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of now, you can't, you're limited to `top | bottom | left | right` for the moment, for such  precision you can modify the display of another plugin such as the [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) jQuery plugin, which was the base for the bootstrap tooltip plugin to begin with.

[Bootdtrap Popover Documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers).

Answer (score 0):

Use "left" instead of "margin-left". The bootstrap popover is using position absolute. Say .popover{left:15px;}